# Forcing a Qt "Hello World" app to build 32 bit - harder than it seems

Tags: qt

Xcode 5.0.1, Mac OS 10.9, Trying to use Qt-Creator 3.0 beta.

I need to use Qt 5.2 with a 32 bit third party library, so I want Qt and my App to be 32 bit. Yes, I know it's 2013... But I have no choice in the matter for now.

I built Qt 5.2 (beta) with the following, did "make" and "make install". All fine.

```
./configure -debug-and-release -commercial -confirm-license -nomake examples -platform macx-clang-32 -arch x86 -no-sql-db2 -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-oci -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-psql  -no-sql-symbian -no-sql-symsql -no-sql-tds  -prefix ~/dev/qt5
```

Now I wanted to test Qt 5.2 by building a simple "Hello World" application. But even tough my Qt is built for 32 bit, and even though the Qt Versions and Kits are set, and I'm using "Clang (x86 32 bit in /usr/bin) as my compiler, I am getting link errors as if my "hello world" application is being built for x86_64.

First I'm getting warnings:

```
"...QtGui.framework/QtGui, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)...   QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)...... etc"
```

Then I'm getting the errors themselves:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "qt_assert(char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      QScopedPointer<QObjectData, QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::operator->() const in moc_mainwindow.o
  "QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*) in mainwindow.o
  "QStatusBar::QStatusBar(QWidget*)", referenced from:
      Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow*) in mainwindow.o
  "QMainWindow::addToolBar(QToolBar*)", referenced from: ..... etc
```

I tried adding this into my *.Pro file:

```
CONFIG += qt x86
CONFIG -= x86_64
```

But it still tries to build X86_64.

How can I force my hello-world application to build for 32 bits and be compatible with the 32 bit Qt framework I've built?

Thanks.

Comment: Try building a simple program using qmake instead. If that works, then there's a problem with the XCode IDE integration.

Comment: I am not using the Xcode IDE. I'm using Qt Creator 3

Comment: OK, in that case, inspect the generated Makefile. There should be `-arch i386` in `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LFLAGS`. If not, insert it manually and see if that fixes it. If yes, it's probably a bug. Maybe it's not picking the correct mkspec. Try forcing it with `qmake -spec macx-clang-32`.

Comment: An interesting observation as you're mentioned XCode -- it seems when I use Qmake to generate an XCode project from my project, and load it up with XCode 5.0.1 -- it builds and runs without problems- making me think there's either a bug, or just a QtCreator 3.0 beta problem that may require more "insisting" on 32 bit output for my hello world app.

Comment: @RM1970 Qt Creator use XCode compile your program, no matter what you do

Comment: @RM1970 Actually it uses the compilers directly without using XCode.

Comment: In any event, try using `qmake` without Qt creator. Just do a `make distclean` and then `qmake`. Then inspect the Makefile.

Comment: Yep, the difference must be in the makefile generation between using Xcode and QtCreator

Comment: Try removing the x86_64 config first, then adding x86 and qt.

Comment: Interesting: when I do this "~/dev/qt5/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang-32 test2.pro" and then "make", it works from command line, inserting "-arch i386" to my build commands. But load the same project in Qt-Creator itself and try this --- It does not include "-arch i386". Can this be forced on Qt-Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, that for the same "hello world" .pro file, I can do this from command line:

```
~/dev/qt5/bin/qmake -spec macx-clang-32 test2.pro
make
```

It will build everything correctly in using 32 bit (i386). It will link correctly with the i386 Qt 5.2 I've built.

**HOWEVER:**

load the same .pro file into Qt-Creator 3 beta: and build -- it will try to build it x86_64 and of course fail on the link.

You can see the difference in the command line: "-arch i386" is added when I do it from command line, but not when I do it from the QtCreator 3.0 beta.

Looking at the exact root cause: I can see that when I use command line the spec is "macx-clang-32". When I use it from within QtCreator 3.0 beta, the spec is "macx-clang".

**So the workaround is:**

I force it back to macx-clang-32 in the project build settings and I can now build 32 fine from within QtCreator 3.0